How to transfer HDMI signal over powerline?
Here's the corrected version of the text in proper English:
Would it be possible to transfer an HDMI signal over powerline using:

An HDMI-to-RJ45 converter, for example, something from AliExpress
A Powerline adapter, for example, the TP-Link PA8010

I would like to use it with my gaming PC and TV. The PC doesn't have a wired connection, and the TV is connected to the LAN via a CAT-5 cable.
Will it work properly?

You cannot; The way those HDMI to CAT converters work is they work as HDMI cables instead of Ethernet cables.  There is no way to combine those converters with a PowerLine converter.

You might try streaming to a small PC (Pi?) over WiFi with plug-in extenders, or wireless HDMI adapters, e.g., https://www.amazon.com/s?k=hdmi+to+wireless+adapter

@DrMoishePippik, thanks, I am afraid there will be a delay with wireless solutions, so it will not be acceptable for games.

@LA_ As you're considering connecting a cable to the PC, why isn't it possible to connect an HDMI cable between the PC and TV?

@AndrewMorton there is a powerline near PC and TV, but there is no ethernet & an HDMI near PC.
